# Masonry doesn't work on moblie browser (chrome) and only works on Chrome desktop version if I reload (ctrl+f5) the page, not on refresh (f5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, sass, jquery-masonry

Masonry doesn't work on moblie browser (chrome) and it doesn't work in Chrome on refresh (f5). It does work correctly if I load the page in any other browser or if I fully reload the page without using its cache (ctrl+5). It also doesn't work on jsfiddle.

I know it should work because the Masonry site itself does work on these browsers.

I'm using a grid size container for defining the column width, and have tiles with different dimensions:

```
    .project {
      width: $column_width;
    }

    .grid-sizer {
    width: $column_width;
  }

    .project.oneXtwo {
    width: $column_width;
    height: (2* $column_width);
    }

    .project.twoXone {
    width: (2* $column_width);
    height: $column_width;
    }

    .project.twoXtwo {
    width: (2* $column_width);
    height: (2* $column_width);
    }
```

Masonry gets initiated on page load:

```
columnWidth = $(".project").width();
        $(".project").height(columnWidth);
        $(".twoXtwo").height(columnWidth * 2);
        $(".oneXtwo").height(columnWidth * 2);

        container.masonry({
          columnWidth: ".grid-sizer",
          itemSelector: '.project',
          isAnimated:true,
        });
```

Here is the jsfiddle for the code: http://jsfiddle.net/BartBurg/BtKHL/
note: in jsfiddle it doesn't work on any other browser either.

Edit:

Firefox also has this problem if I reload the page by accessing the website for the second time (not on refresh/reload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was farfetched and will probably only occur very rarely.

I am using scssphp to parse my .SCSS files server side. I included my SCSS and JS files in this matter:

```
<!-- Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link type="text/css" href="style.php/responsive.scss" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And the solution was to include the Stylesheets before I include any Javascript:

```
<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link type="text/css" href="style.php/responsive.scss" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

This is interesting because I initiate masonry on jQuery.ready():

```
$( function() {
    ...
    initMasonry(container);
});

function initMasonry(container){
    ...
    container.masonry({
      columnWidth: ".grid-sizer",
      itemSelector: '.project',
          isAnimated:true
    });
    ...
}
```

If I replace the stylesheet with the generated .css stylesheet, masonry also works as expected.

My wild guess is that both Chrome and Firefox fire the DOM ready event when they see all the lines with *.js and *.css are loaded correctly and will not wait for pending *.scss files.

It is a mystery to me why this works on full page reload (ctrl+f5) and not on refresh (f5)